# VSCode Error with Schema for Azure DevOps Yaml extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, yaml, vscode-extensions

I am trying to work with my usersettings.json file and make sure that on a particular file type it uses the Azure DevOps Schema, for syntax checking. Yet I keep getting this error when loading in a .yml file:

`Problems loading reference 'schemaservice://combinedschema/azure-devops': Unable to load schema from 'schemaservice://combinedschema/azure-devops': No content` (note for my setup .yaml is reserved for kubernetes yaml)

I was wondering if anyone else had come across this problem before, I have been following this repo for setting up my user settings: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode and this document: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines

Here is my usersettings.json file

```html
{
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Jason\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\helm\\windows-amd64\\helm.exe",
        "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Jason\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\minikube\\windows-amd64\\minikube.exe"
    },
    "files.associations": {
            "**/ci/*.yml": "azure-pipelines"
        },
    "[azure-pipelines]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong in the end for some reason in my settings VSCode can not resolve: "http://www.schemastore.org/json/composer"

Now this was not originally appearing in my usersettings.json but was being used what VSCode Was referring to was a hidden file in my project area called .vscode once I deleted that it then brought up the right file with the json schema.

I have since changed my settings to use the camel schema.

Here are my settings also with these settings you can now diffrentiate between an azure devops yaml file and kuberneted yaml file. As long as you have on the end of your kubernetes file _kube.yaml This will then let vscode know im working on a kubernetes file use the relevant schema.

```html
{
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "yaml.schemas": {
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-vscode/master/service-schema.json": "*.yml",
       // "http://www.schemastore.org/json/composer": ["/*"],
       "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/camel/main/dsl/camel-yaml-dsl/camel-yaml-dsl/src/generated/resources/camel-yaml-dsl.json" : "/_kube*.yaml", 
       "kubernetes": ["/*.yaml"]
    },
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vscode-kubernetes.helm-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Jason\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\helm\\windows-amd64\\helm.exe",
        "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path.windows": "C:\\Users\\Jason\\.vs-kubernetes\\tools\\minikube\\windows-amd64\\minikube.exe"
    },
    "files.associations": {
            "**/ci/*.yml": "azure-pipelines"
        },
    "[azure-pipelines]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
        },
        "yaml.schemaStore.url": "http://www.schemastore.org/api/json/catalog.json",
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jason, thanks for sharing. You could [mark your answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that people with the same questions can benefit.